# Stripe. Customer to user payments

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

My app has `clients` and `providers`.

Clients **can pay to providers**, providers **CAN'T pay to clients**.
I have provider **Bank** data, and when a client pays to a provider, the money should be transfered to the **provider bank** account

Can I do that functionality with Stripe and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Stripe Connect to facilitate payments to a "provider" aka a Connect account. https://stripe.com/docs/connect.